# How to put a SQL query in Excel with where clause

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has customer data. I have a SQL Server database that contains additional information about the customer. Is there a way to query my SQL Server database to populate a column in my Excel spreadsheet?

For example: in my spreadsheet I have a customer number that matches a customer number in my database. Can I query the spreadsheet to get the city name from my database and output it to my spreadsheet?

I would assume I can do something like

```
SELECT city 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE custNum = [excel column with customer number]
```

I'm an absolute noob when it comes to Excel so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you need to query data from SQL Server in Excel. If it is ok, take a look at the following link. It helps you to connect a SQL Server database: [Connect a SQL Server database to your workbook (Power Query)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-a-sql-server-database-to-your-workbook-power-query-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad)

Comment: You can import the excel data into the database table and compare the data using the sql query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You can use MS Access as the happy medium: join linked table to linked worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your assistance. I ended up creating this select statement:

```
SELECT custNum, city FROM customer
```

Then exported that output to an excel spreadsheet and used VLOOKUP() to link the spreadsheets and put the city information in my original spreadsheet